# Символ & перед переменной в php

Tags: php

Что означает `&` перед переменной при переборе данных массива?

```
foreach ($this->data as $id=>&$node) {}
```

Comment: Это ссылка. На самом деле символ относится к оператору  `=>&`. Если в теле цикла вы присвоите новое значение переменной `$node`, то оно сохранится в массиве `$this->data`. Очень часто это не нужно, поскольку используется механизм COW, если только вы действительно не планируете менять элементы массива в цикле.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Хм.. т.е. это избавит от конструкции в теле цикла типа `$this->data[$id]=...`, если бы я переназначал значения этого массива?

Comment: Тут затрудняюсь ответить. Дело в том, что в PHP нет настоящих массивов, а есть только хеши, ключи которых связаны в цепь для возможности перечисления (foreach) в порядке добавления. Если `$this->data[$id]=...` работает с уже существующим элементом хеша, не меняя его  цепочной связи с соседними, то все будет именно так.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Благодарю. Не будете оформлять ответ?

Comment: вроде, не тянет на полноценный ответ.

Comment: Это полезно не только если необходимо менять исходный массив. (на мой взгляд). Без этого по сути внутри создается новая переменная и в нее копируется значение (а она может быть большим массивом), если со знаком & то работа идет с готовым массивом и адресацией по нему - т.е. на работу скрипта тратится меньше процессорного времени

Comment: @AlexanderZonov Тянет. но в комментариях я ответ не смогу засчитать)

Comment: @ВоробьевАлександр, именно, **нет**. Используется механизм Copy-on-Write.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov это точно относится к элементам массива? Я думал COW касается всего массива в целом... Т.е. типа под капотом foreach это функция в которую передается массив в качестве параметра

Comment: Это относится к любым переменным, в том числе, элементам массивов.

Comment: @ВоробьевАлександр, наоборот, использование явных ссылок может вести к потери производительности из-за того, что сработает copy on write для самого массива.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У вас есть два варианта цикла:

```
foreach ($this->data as $id => $node) {}
```

и (вариант со ссылкой)

```
foreach ($this->data as $id =>& $node) {}
```

Разница только лишь в возможности во втором случае изменить элемент массива `$node` простым присвоением `$node = 123`.

Никакого замедления или копирования данных, если не используются ссылки, не происходит, поскольку PHP использует механизм Copy-on-Write. В варианте цикла без ссылки программисту просто запрещается использовать ссылку, но внутри движка PHP она все так же имеет место.